# Geopandas - Is it possible to undo an unknown translation?

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I have two different maps of Spain:

- The first one shows the scale of risk of the whole Spanish territory
- The second one shows the shapes of the different municipalities.

I need to overlap those maps to compute the area of the different risks inside each municipality. However, the first map has the Canary Islands "moved" from their original position:

[Both Maps Together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYHqj.png)

Also, for visualization purposes, it would be nice to have both of them in the same "position".

The first thing I noticed is that the CRS of each map is different so I changed it using the .to_crs() method to convert the first one to the same as the first one (epsg:4326).

I have been trying several things but I could not find any way to make both maps match. The one that worked the best has been to compute the most southwest point and make both of them match, but the result is not the desired one:

[Try using the most southwest point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHAYW.png)

Here you have some of the code used:

```
radon = gpd.read_file('./data/potencial_radon.gdb', layer=fiona.listlayers('./data/radon.gdb')[0]).to_crs(epsg=4326)
municipalities = gpd.read_file('./data/municipalities.gdb').to_crs(epsg=4326)

#Radon has 8 rows (3 for the Canary islands and 5 for the levels of the Iberian Peninsula + Balearic Islands + Morocco Territories)

#Select the canary islands
for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    # Translate each one using the most South-West point
    moved_radon.at[i, 'geometry'] = shapely.affinity.translate(moved_radon.loc[i]['geometry'],
                                     xoff=min(municipalities_bounds['minx']) - min(radon_bounds['minx']), 
                                     yoff=min(municipalities_bounds['miny']) - min(radon_bounds['miny']))
```

Comment: If it is `known` translation, you can translate it back (undoing) with negative values of the previous move.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, the problem is that I do not know the translation done since these are maps from different sources and unfortunately, the source of the first one is not answering me.